# Cannot change width and height of custom component in React-native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, components, react-native-flexbox

I have a minimal custom stateless component like this:

```
const ViewBox = (props) => (
    <View style={ mainStyle : {backgroundColor: 'beige'} }>
        {props.children}
    </View>
)
export default ViewBox;
```

so I want to import and use it inside another component.

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerView} >
            <ViewBox style={styles.mainBox}>
              <Text style={[styles.boxTitle, {color: '#8F468C'}]}>Lorem ipsum...</Text>
            </ViewBox>
        </View>
    );
    }
}

const styles = {    
  containerView: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'brown',
  },
  mainBox: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 250,  //No effect ! ! !
    height: 250  //No effect ! ! !
  },
  boxTitle: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    fontSize: 17,
    marginTop: 20
  }
};
```

Here we have at least 2 inexplicable facts:
1) and more important the width and height of the ViewBox (or every **custom** component you want to use here) **is totally out of control**! Assigning numeric size or Flex values has no effect and ViewBox keeps the minimum width/height needed to render the inner Text.

[image]

2) Removing the root View (so the ViewBox became the root) ViewBox continue ignoring any size, but now it fills all the space available.... WHY???

[image]

All mentioned behavoirs occurs using a custom View (ViewBox in this case), instead if replace it with a normal View all works as expected.
I guess to know enough flex and UI best practices for React-native, but such two cases are not well covered by docs. Hope somebody can surprise me!

Comment: So what you want to achieve exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually how flexbox works:

1. Flex containers come with `flexShrink: 1` by default meaning that they will shrink to their contents. Adding `flexShrink: 0` changes that. You may need to use `minWidth` and `minHeight` with that instead.
2. The reason why it stretches is because there's nothing to tell it otherwise. Your container has the default `alignItems: 'stretch'` overwritten with `alignItems: 'center'` which shrinks its contents.

Have a look at the example code on Snack: https://snack.expo.io/B1VdUma1M

There's a really nice flexbox cheatsheet/playground that shows the behaviour at: https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/

Bear in mind [React Native's implementation is slightly different](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/understanding-react-native-flexbox-layout-7a528200afd4).

Comment: Perfect answer man! Just one last query: according to the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) the flexShrink prop controls how "Flex items will shrink to fill the container" not the contrary as you said. I'm a bit confusing about this.